# Unit test lazy loading of images in AngularJS with Jasmine and Karma?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive, phantomjs, karma-runner

I have used the lazy loading of images solution from Ben Nadel's blog: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2498-lazy-loading-image-with-angularjs.htm and modified it slightly to work as we want. No problem with the functionality so far, but we would like to have unit tests on this functionality, to be sure that it is in fact always working as expected.

I want to test that the image has the correct source when loading (this is not a problem), and that it will be changed when the image comes into the viewport (this is a big problem). Is it possible to do this with unit tests in PhantomJS, or do we have to use E2E tests with Protractor?

Comment: If you are testing interaction with the DOM (`comes into the viewport`), then you are most likely in need of an e2e or protractor test.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes, I want to test that the image src is switched to the correct url when the image comes into the viewport, or if the image already is in the viewport on page load. Ok, so there is no way to fake this with unit tests in Jasmine with PhantomJS as browser? (I know I'm probably just grasping for straws here..)

Comment: You can run protractor in phantomjs as well.  But if you need to affect the DOM, you need web driver to interact with it.